# How can I deploy android apps using a manifest file, similar to iOS devices, without using an app store?

Tags: android, mobile, deployment, android-manifest

I want to deploy an Android app in a similar fashion as the Wireless, Over-The-Air method that exists for iOS devices.  That is, setup a web page and the user clicks a link from his device that includes the manifest (xml) file, containing information on how to download the app.  This works well on iOS devices, and I thought Android may have something similar.

How do I go about this?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can just link to the apk, they download and they install. The only thing the user has to be sure of is that the option for loading non-market apps is set properly (typically under settings/apps or settings/developer options). The only time this wouldn't be possible, as far as I know, is on certain AT&T phones

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  So, if the user does not enable apps from unknown sources (non-market), he or she cannot download and install the Android app.  As you said, some phones gray out or hide this feature.  In those cases, is there any other way to allow the user to download the file, other than putting it on an app store?

Comment: Ask them to `adb install yourprogram.apk` from the computer.

Comment: if that option is grayed out, it has to come from the market/play store, but I believe there was enough complaints that AT&T updated the software to allow it, although I don't know 100%. And by the way, in ICS, it's in settings/security on my phone.

Comment: Thank you very much, NoBugs.  Well, it's for a large number of users for an organization.  I'll have to write a routine, then, that will automate this task.  Thanks again.

Comment: Also, it is important to note to have the correct MIME settings for your server.  In my case, it's an IIS server.  The MIME settings are: .apk; application/vnd.android.package-archive

Answer (score 0):

Please the comments above.  Have the correct MIME settings, link to the apk, and make sure unknown sources is checked on the device to allow non-market apps.

Answer (score 0):

- Since you seem to imply an app market / store is not involved in the iOS case, it seems you might be talking about an offline-cacheable "web app" rather than a native iOS application.

  The android equivalent is: on devices where the offline web app capability exists, just visit the same web page (referencing an html5 manifest with appropriate mime type, etc) you are using for iOS.  Perhaps you will ultimately end up with platform-specific refinements, but the basic idea is portable.
- Or perhaps you just mean that a desktop/laptop need not be used to open obtain the app.  On Android, that has been the case since day 1 - the primary market client is on the device, with over-the-air install.  You can send an android device to the market with a market:// url.  The ability to trigger an install from a web browser running on something other than the device is a more recent and still secondary capability on android.
- Finally, android does offer the ability to side load native applications, something that has no iOS equivalent outside of jailbreaking or having a developer account.  Most of the responses seem to concentrate on this, but it's not clear if that is what you are actually asking for.